# Is jquery CDN while using a VPN possible? - Using TamperMonkey

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts, tampermonkey

I wrote a script to run in TamperMonkey that works properly when I do not have VPN enabled.

When VPN/proxy is enabled and I attempt to use the TamperMonkey Script, it no longer works and provides $ is not defined errors.

I use `@require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js`

I believe the VPN is the issue. How can I access jquery for my TamperMonkey script to work properly while running the VPN?

Comment: You can look for other links for jQuery, they're all over, there probably at least one that's not blocked. I wonder if the @require'd data is stored somewhere - I know GM 3 saved it directly to the script location in the file system

Comment: Thanks! Tried Microsoft, Google, cdnjs.. no dice. Would be great if I can find another one, will search around. Trying to figure out how to do it locally for now.

Comment: Huh, that's unfortunate. If there isn't an answer of how to save it locally, you can consider (1) refactoring the userscript to not use jQuery, or (2) pasting the content of jQuery inline in the userscript (disgustingly ugly, but it would work - look up Webpack for how to do this in a more official manner)

Comment: Honestly that may be easiest at this point. Didn't even realize I could do that, just paste the entire thing inline? That's hilarious. I'll look up Webpack.

Comment: Do I just paste entire jquery content at the top? Gave me bunch of errors, I feel like i need to add something before and after but don't know what..

Comment: Not at the very top, that's reserved for the userscript declaration - try putting it right after that

Comment: Gave a large series of errors unfortunately. Too many to begin to type. Unexpected use of comman, 'module' not defined, return statement should not contain assignment, etc etc.. 

I can live without this script was just experimenting anyway lol

Comment: Those are linter errors, not Javascript errors. Ignore the linter.

Comment: Ok ignored linter, still seeing $ not defined error - do I have to set var $ to something? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you [download](https://jquery.com/download/) it and self host for offline usage?

Comment: Just downloaded the file and changed code to ```// @require      file:///C:/Users/name/Desktop/jquery-3.4.0.min``` but the same issue of $ not defined persists. I think Firefox/TamperMonkey is having trouble pulling from a local file. Must be a security setting i need to find.

Comment: @MarcNewton Do note that this is a userscript, not a standard `<script>` tag - it's not hosted on the site it's being used on

Comment: Ah i see, you are not actually coding a website. Perhaps you could run a localhost https server to serve the file from your machine and essentially use http://localhost/jquery-3.4.0.min as a work around?
https://flaviocopes.com/local-web-server/
I assume this is just for development purposes of a plugin?

Comment: Thanks! Will go that route - appreciate the help guys! Yes just a plugin.